# The colors of the PopupMenuItems and Cards are wrong after Flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui

The colors of `PopupMenuItems` and `Cards` must match the background of the `PopupMenu` and `Cards` color. Before the update the colors were wrong and to fix it I used `ElevationOverlay.applySurfaceTint` but now this doesn't work. I tried everything I know.

[image]

AppBar Code:

```
appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        elevation: 4,
        surfaceTintColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceTint,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
        title: const Text('Asistente'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton( 
              position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
              // color: ElevationOverlay.applySurfaceTint(
              //     Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
              //     Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceTint,
              //     2),
              elevation: 2,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: 112,
                maxWidth: 280,
              ),
              iconSize: 30,
              icon: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoURL!),
              ),
              // icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: ListTile(
                        iconColor:
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                        onTap: (() {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          openDialog(context);
                        }),
                        title: Text(
                          'Configuración',
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .labelLarge
                              ?.copyWith(
                                  color:
                                      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: ListTile(
                        iconColor:
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                        onTap: (() {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          infoDialog(context);
                        }),
                        title: Text(
                          'Información',
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .labelLarge
                              ?.copyWith(
                                  color:
                                      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: ListTile(
                        iconColor:
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.logout_outlined),
                        onTap: (() {
                          final provider = Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(
                              context,
                              listen: false);
                          provider.logout();
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        }),
                        title: Text(
                          'Cerrar Sesión',
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .labelLarge
                              ?.copyWith(
                                  color:
                                      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ])
        ],
      ),
```

For theming I'm using Material 3 with color scheme

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => GoogleSignInProvider(),
      child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(builder: (context, provider, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Tesis',
          theme: ThemeData(
            useMaterial3: true,
            colorScheme: lightColorScheme,
          ),
          darkTheme: ThemeData(
            useMaterial3: true,
            colorScheme: darkColorScheme,
          ),
          themeMode: provider.themeMode,
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/': (context) => const Start(),
            '/second': (context) => const Home(),
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Color Scheme

```
const lightColorScheme = ColorScheme(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  surfaceTint: Color(0xFF6750A4),
  onErrorContainer: Color(0xFF410E0B),
  onError: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
  errorContainer: Color(0xFFF9DEDC),
  onTertiaryContainer: Color(0xFF31111D),
  onTertiary: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
  tertiaryContainer: Color(0xFFFFD8E4),
  tertiary: Color(0xFF7D5260),
  shadow: Color(0xFF000000),
  error: Color(0xFFB3261E),
  outline: Color(0xFF79747E),
  onBackground: Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
  background: Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
  onInverseSurface: Color(0xFFF4EFF4),
  inverseSurface: Color(0xFF313033),
  onSurfaceVariant: Color(0xFF49454F),
  onSurface: Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
  surfaceVariant: Color(0xFFE7E0EC),
  surface: Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
  onSecondaryContainer: Color(0xFF1D192B),
  onSecondary: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
  secondaryContainer: Color(0xFFE8DEF8),
  secondary: Color(0xFF625B71),
  inversePrimary: Color(0xFFD0BCFF),
  onPrimaryContainer: Color(0xFF21005D),
  onPrimary: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
  primaryContainer: Color(0xFFEADDFF),
  primary: Color(0xFF6750A4),
);

const darkColorScheme = ColorScheme(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  surfaceTint: Color(0xFFD0BCFF),
  onErrorContainer: Color(0xFFF2B8B5),
  onError: Color(0xFF601410),
  errorContainer: Color(0xFF8C1D18),
  onTertiaryContainer: Color(0xFFFFD8E4),
  onTertiary: Color(0xFF492532),
  tertiaryContainer: Color(0xFF633B48),
  tertiary: Color(0xFFEFB8C8),
  shadow: Color(0xFF000000),
  error: Color(0xFFF2B8B5),
  outline: Color(0xFF938F99),
  onBackground: Color(0xFFE6E1E5),
  background: Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
  onInverseSurface: Color(0xFF313033),
  inverseSurface: Color(0xFFE6E1E5),
  onSurfaceVariant: Color(0xFFCAC4D0),
  onSurface: Color(0xFFE6E1E5),
  surfaceVariant: Color(0xFF49454F),
  surface: Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
  onSecondaryContainer: Color(0xFFE8DEF8),
  onSecondary: Color(0xFF332D41),
  secondaryContainer: Color(0xFF4A4458),
  secondary: Color(0xFFCCC2DC),
  inversePrimary: Color(0xFF6750A4),
  onPrimaryContainer: Color(0xFFEADDFF),
  onPrimary: Color(0xFF381E72),
  primaryContainer: Color(0xFF4F378B),
  primary: Color(0xFFD0BCFF),
);
```

Comment: Have your tried using `color: Colors.transparent` for the card?

Comment: But I don't want my card to be transparent and it doesn't work either, it just changes the color below, where the name is and "Price" is still different

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: Sure, i already added the code, i try removing the ListTiles but the ontap function don't work this way

Comment: @WilldersCarvajal I was not able to reproduce the issue with Android or Web. 
Can't you just change the ```ListTile(tileColor:``` to match the background color?

Comment: No, for some reason, that doesn't work, i test with all the parameter of the tile

Comment: Please produce the theme you are using, So that i can help

Comment: edited, as i mention on the post i use material 3 and color scheme

Comment: @WilldersCarvajal I am still unable to reproduce the issue. Does this happen in every platform and device? Have you tested desktop, web or other phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a compatibility conflict between the new versions and the `ListTile` on the `Cards` and `PopupMenu`. The solution was to remove the `ListTile`.

The new `PopupMenu`:

```
actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<Item>(
            position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
            initialValue: selectedMenu,
            onSelected: (Item item) {
              setState(() {
                selectedMenu = item;
                if (selectedMenu == Item.itemOne) {
                  infoDialog(context);
                } else if (selectedMenu == Item.itemTwo) {
                  openDialog(context);
                } else if (selectedMenu == Item.itemThree) {
                  final provider =
                      Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: false);
                  provider.logout();
                }
              });
            },
            itemBuilder: (context) => [
              PopupMenuItem<Item>(
                value: Item.itemOne,
                child: Row(
                  children: const [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                      child: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Información',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              PopupMenuItem<Item>(
                value: Item.itemTwo,
                child: Row(
                  children: const [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                      child: Icon(Icons.settings),
                    ),
                    Text('Configuración'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              PopupMenuItem<Item>(
                value: Item.itemThree,
                child: Row(
                  children: const [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                      child: Icon(Icons.logout_outlined),
                    ),
                    Text('Cerrar Sesión'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoURL!),
            ),
          )
        ],
```

The new `Cards`:

```
Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 300,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Image(
              image: NetworkImage(widget.products.imageUrl),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 0, 0),
              child: Text(
                widget.products.name,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
              child: Text('Precio: ${widget.products.price}\$'),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text('Cantidad: '),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                    child: QuantityMenu(
                      quantityFuction: quantityFunction,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 8),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                        const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                        const Color(0xFF6750A4),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                        title: SizedBox(
                          width: 240,
                          height: 260,
                          child: QrImage(
                            data: data,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        content: Text('ID del producto: $data'),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: const Text('Cerrar')),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Mostrar QR',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 8),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                        const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                        const Color(0xFF6750A4),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                        title: Text(
                          '¿Desea eliminar el producto ${widget.products.name} de la base de datos?',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: const Text('Cancelar')),
                          TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                final docProducts = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                    .collection('products')
                                    .doc(widget.products.id);

                                docProducts.delete();
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: const Text('Eliminar')),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Eliminar',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 8),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                        const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                        const Color(0xFF6750A4),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                        content: Text(
                          '¿Desea añadir $quantity ${widget.products.name}(s) a la lista de compras? \n \n'
                          'Atencion!: Si este producto ya se encuentra en el carrito añadirlo de nuevo reemplazará el anterior',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: const Text('Cancelar')),
                          TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                double total = widget.products.price *
                                    double.parse(quantity);
                                addToList(
                                        id: widget.products.id,
                                        total: total,
                                        name: widget.products.name,
                                        price: widget.products.price,
                                        imgUrl: widget.products.imageUrl,
                                        quantity: quantity)
                                    .then((value) => Navigator.pop(context));
                              },
                              child: const Text('Añadir')),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Añadir al Carro',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```